# The difference between SAML and oAuth (JWT authentication)

Tags: authentication, oauth, jwt, authorization, saml

Does anyone can explain the difference and pros and cons in detail of calling Gateway with JWT token, converting it to JWT to SAML assertion and directly invoking by passing a JWT?

Answer (score 0):

You can't mix and match.

SAML tokens are XML.

OIDC tokens are JSON.

If you have a JWT and try and create a SAML token, the signature will be totally different, and the caller will expect an OIDC response.

You can't convert JWT to SAML assertions and then pass JWT.

SAML assertions are not part of the OIDC JWT standard.